# Reduce 1024 images to one

Tags: opencl

I read the paper about reducing a 1d array to one value in openCL ( http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/ ) and I understood the concept of associative operators. Extending this concept to ONE 2d array should also be possible.

But my problem is somewhat different: I have ~1000 images of 256x256 pixels with 16bit each and I would like to sum all these images to finally have the average image of them all. The usual GPU should have enough memory (~130Mb) to perform this task, but I don't really see how to implement the kernel.

Comment: do you have more information about your image format? are pixels float2, uint2, or something else? do you need to read from an image or as global memory?

Answer (score 1):

Just as the 1D problem extends to 2D, it can also extend to 3D (which is what you have: 1000x256x256).

Exactly the same principles would apply:
1. Try to do as much work in parallel as you can without contention with other work groups.
2. Do the reduction in stages so each can be parallel.

Your likely going to be bandwidth limited, churning through 131 MB of memory, but that's not really a problem. Just write the kernels to do coalesced reads for maximum performance.